# Непереведенный текст в очереди проверок "Предлагаемые правки"

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-запланировано, локализация

Вот такой текст имеется:

> - **Принять** edits that clearly improve the post
> - **Улучшить правку** when you can make additional improvements to the post
> - **Отклонить и редактировать** to replace an ineffective edit with your own substantive changes
> - **Отклонить** edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> - **Пропустить** , если вы не уверены и хотите перейти к следующей предлагаемой правке

Ну и по мелочи: лишний пробел перед запятой в последнем предложении.

Comment: Странно, вроде были уже переводы.

Comment: Проверил, сейчас не все строки воспроизведены. В ближайшее время поправим.